# best java jabber client library

Tags: java, chat, xmpp, instant-messaging

What good/bad experiences do you have with java jabber libraries?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've had really good experience with the [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) library.  I found it straightforward to use, and pretty easy to get a basic client up and running.  The documentation was pretty good as well.

Comment: +1 for smack, does the job, well-written.

Comment: We've used Smack (and Spark IM client and Ignite IM server) for quite some time - been very happy with it.

Comment: I'm also happy with smack. The only downside is the lack of support for BOSH (XMPP over HTTP), very useful for clients behind corporate firewalls.

Comment: @alves There is an [open ticket](http://issues.igniterealtime.org/browse/SMACK-187) for BOSH support on smack and an [branch on their vcs](http://fisheye.igniterealtime.org/changelog/smack/branches/bosh/smack-bosh). Support from the community is always welcome. :-)