# Does Java have any API for Gmail chat?

Tags: java, oauth

I'm trying to make a chat application for Gmail on Java, but I couldn't find any API for this purpose. I was told about OAuth but I don't think it has any such feature. Please suggest me an API or help me use OAuth in this situation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google uses the XMPP protocol for its chats.

- [XMPP Java API Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview)
- a [simple tutorial](http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/wp/2008/12/30/using-google-talk-from-java-example/) using the [Smack](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack/index.jsp) library

Answer (score 0):

Gmail utilises a web-based version of Google Talk (GTalk). GTalk is a Jabber/XMPP-based chat system.

I'd recommend looking at a Jabber/XMPP library for Java, such as Smack, noted as an answer in this question; [best java jabber client library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091625/best-java-jabber-client-library)

Answer (score 0):

Google Chat, and Google Talk, use the XMPP protocol. You might find it useful to read the Google documentation here... https://developers.google.com/talk/